# Make "find and replace" both refer to normal lines of code and commented out lines of code

Tags: r, replace, find, comments

Using RStudio

If I mark/select the part of the code below that doesn't have a 2 in it...

```
# hello
hello <- hello

# hello2
hello2 <- hello2
```

...And I then use command + F to get the search up, search for `hello` and replace with `goodbye` (and tick off 'in selection', what I would expect to get is this...

```
# goodbye
goodbye <- goodbye

# hello2
hello2 <- hello2
```

... however, what I actually get, is this...

```
# hello
goodbye <- goodbye

# hello2
hello2 <- hello2
```

Why does the text after the # not get replaced?

Comment: First: impossible to answer without specs over system/IDE used. Second: This is not an R problem.

Comment: Ah yes I see. Where should I go with my question about rstudio?

Comment: not sure.. also: I get the desired behaviour (windows 10, rstudio #2022.12.0 Build 353). Commented lines get replaced as well